# Как усовершенствовать скрипт php?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть следующий скрипт:

```
    <?php
    $handle = @fopen('base.txt', 'r') or die('Не удалось открыть файл'); // открываем файл

    /* читаем файл построчно*/
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $read[] = fgets($handle);
    }

    /*распечатаем массив
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($read);
    echo '</pre>';
    */

    /*разбираем строки на элементы*/

    $i = 0;
    foreach($read as $item){
        if(!empty($item)){
            $data[] = explode('//', $item);
            echo '<div class="question">' .$data[$i][0]. '</div>';
            echo '<div class="answer">' .$data[$i][1]. '</div>';
            $i++;
        }           
    }

    fclose($handle); // закрываем файл
    ?>
```

Скрипт предназначен для организации раздела FAQ на сайте. Он выводит список вопрос-ответ, беря данные из текстового файла(base.txt). Однако мне он очень подходит для создания адресно-телефонного справочника. Есть только один недостаток, мне бы хотелось, чтобы данные об организациях выводились не только общим списком, но и для каждой орг-ции в отдельной странице, то есть как это и принято в современных интернет-справочниках (yell.ru, например).

Поэтому, помогите сделать так, чтобы в данном скрипте, к примеру, строка

```
echo '<div class="question">'.$data[$i][0].'</div>';
```

где выводится вопрос, была бы еще и ссылкой на файл, где в отдельном окне выводился бы соответствующий вопрос-ответ из одной базы данных. Это будет очень удобно. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил, чего хочу. Буду весьма признателен за такую помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Простейший вариант, если не использовать движок БД:

```
// Есть ли запрос конкретного нода?
//if(empty($_REQUEST['node']) || !isset($read[$_REQUEST['node']])){
  if(!isset($_REQUEST['node']) || !isset($read[$_REQUEST['node']])){   
//Нет: выводим полный список.
$i = 0;
    foreach($read as $item){
        if(!empty($item)){
            $data[] = explode('//', $item);
            echo '<div class="question"><a href="spisok.php?node='.$i.'">' .$data[$i][0]. '</a></div>';
            echo '<div class="answer"><a href="spisok.php?node='.$i.'">' .$data[$i][1]. '</a></div>';
            $i++;
        }           
    }
}else{
//Да, выводим один нод
    echo '<a href="spisok.php">назад, к списку</a>';  
    $data = explode('//', $read[$_REQUEST['node']]);
    echo '<div class="question">' .$data[0]. '</div>';
    echo '<div class="answer">' .$data[1]. '</div>';
}
```

Ну или как-то так.

Comment: Ну или как-то так. //так, так.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, сейчас буду разбирать))

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, реализовал Ваш вариант, получилось! Только первый пункт не делает переход по ссылке, почему?

Comment: Потому что зараза empty() сочла int=0 за пустое значение.  

    empty($_REQUEST['node'])  

Придется проверять на isset() и >=0

Comment: knes, что-то я не пойму, как с Вами связаться?

Answer (score 1):

Боже.. переходите на использование базы данных.

а вообще

```
echo '<a href="some_url.php?org=name_of_org">' .$data[$i][0]. '</a>';
```

---

```
if($_GET['org'])
{
echo 'то что надо';
}
```

Comment: переходите на использование базы данных.// Дадада! =) 
Но ТЗ есть ТЗ. Может, там хостинг древний, которые еще не все поддерживали БД.

Comment: я думал такое только в сказках бывает =( а вот оно как оказывается

Comment: Увы, такое бывает не только в сказках, увы. =/

Comment: Спасибо, друзья! Попробую разобраться. Что касается текстовых файлов и БД, специфика работы такая, хожу по предприятиям города, собираю инфу и тут же заношу в смартфон и передаю на сервер. Все просто и понятно. Как при этом перейти на использование БД я, не будучи программером, даже представить не могу. Да, слышал есть такая SQLite, но что за зверь и с чем едят, а тем более как использовать вместе с этим скриптом, увы не знаю)) Если есть какие-то рекомендации, буду весьма признателен.

Comment: Хочу добавить по поводу баз данных. БД является универсальным хранилищем, удобным и структурированным. В каждой операционной системе, разные стандарты по поводу файлов и папок(могут быть ошибки).
А по поводу древних хостингов, используйте xml файлы и их структуру, удобнее.

Comment: Да я рад бы использовать БД! Но поскольку знания мои ограничены, поэтому, вот, имею данный скрипт, теперь усовершенствованный, спасибо всем. Как его использовать совместно с БД знать не знаю, буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не поместить весь текст в массив? Тогда можно через serialize() записать его в файл, а потом при чтении файла сделать  unserialize(). Тогда ты сможешь для каждой организации создать отдельный ассоциативный массив внутри основного, и их уже обрабатывать в цикле.